# Converting a signed int32 to an unsigned int64

Tags: c

```
int main(){
  unsigned long a = 5;
  int b = -6;

  long c = a + b;

  return 0;
}
```

I wanted to follow the rules explined in this link and confirm my understanding
of how the compiler emits code for `a + b`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

1- `b` is first converted to an `unsigned long`:

> If the unsigned type has conversion rank greater than or equal to the rank of the signed type, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type.

So the the compiler essentially does this:

```
unsigned long implicit_conversion_of_b = (unsigned long) b;
```

2- The above implicit conversion itself is covered with this rule under `Integer conversions`:

> if the target type is unsigned, the value 2b
> , where b is the number of bits in the target type, is repeatedly subtracted or added to the source value until the result fits in the target type.

3- We finlay end up with these 64-bit values in a register before addition takes place:

```
a = 0x5
b = 0xfffffffffffffffa
```

Is the above a correct mapping to the rules?

##### Edit:

4- The final result is an `unsigned long` which needs to be converted to `long` needed b `c` using this rule:

> otherwise, if the target type is signed, the behavior is implementation-defined (which may include raising a signal)

Comment: did you run the code and see?

Comment: yes, but It's hard to tell by just looking at the emitted code. The compiler can do all sorts of optimizations even with `-O0`, this is more like a theoretical question.

Comment: You left out the wild-card, btw: the conversion from `unsigned long` to `long`, after the addition, of an unsigned long value that cannot be represented by long. Ru ro.

Comment: I have no problems with "am I interpreting this correctly" style of questions. I wish all questions were as clear as this one. But for some reason, they get downvoted a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the above a correct mapping to the rules?

Yes.

Comment: Could you confirm if my `Edit` is also correct?

Comment: Yes, because `0xffffffffffffffff` can't be represented as `long`, but otherwise it's just converted to long.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no assembly expert, but it's interesting to see what's happening here.  Not sure what optimizations you're talking about compiling with `-O0` (seen below), obviously `-O2` and `-O3` look a lot different:

```
main:
        // setup stack
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        // move 5 into 8-byte offset from the stack frame.
        // rbp is the stack frame pointer, offset of 8 shows long is 8
        // bytes on this architecture
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 5
        // move -6 to 12 bytes offset from rbp (or 4 byte offset from
        // last value. This tells you int is 4 bytes on this architecture.
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], -6
        // move the int into eax register. This is a 32-bit general
        // purpose register
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        // movsx is a "move with sign extension" instruction. rdx is a
        // 64-bit register, so this is your conversion from 32 to 64
        // bits, preserving the sign
        movsx   rdx, eax
        // moves 5 to the 64-bit rax register
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        // performs the 64-bit add
        add     rax, rdx
        // not using the result, so cleanup, prepare to return
        // from function
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

This assembly was [generated with gcc 11.2 on x64-86](https://godbolt.org/z/9Gq519eea)

Comment: Optimization would clean up the many redundant moves, though you'd have to do a little more work to keep it from just propagating the constants and/or optimizing out the code having no effect.  But the core of the work is "sign extend `b` to 64 bits, then do a 64-bit add".